# Анимация открытия изображения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        #pic {
            position:relative;
            background: url(pic.jpg);
            margin: auto;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            top: 100px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pic"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать, чтобы картинка плавно открывалась снизу вверх (как сделать, чтобы она открывалась сверху вниз я знаю). Если по кадрам, то это должно выглядеть примерно так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Ну и все время раскрытия изображения - 1 секунда.

Картинка при этом должна оставаться статичной, посередине, не двигаться относительно других блоков.
Как это реализовать на js(jQuery)/css?

Comment: А блок с картинкой у вас сверстан? Вставьте его в вопрос

Comment: @Chag ок, добавил

Comment: А картинка должна появляться сразу или при каком-то событии?

Comment: @Chag, неважно, можно и сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать jQuery метод `.slideDown()`:

```js
$('.pic-inner').slideDown(1000);
```

```css
#pic {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.pic-inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000 url(pic.jpg);
  background-position: center bottom;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic">
  <div class="pic-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем. Так картинка двигается внутри блока. То есть получается, что енот высовывает голову. Нужно, чтобы картинка открывалась, енот оставался неподвижным.

Comment: @ArturKharchenko добавьте в css `background-position:center bottom;`

Comment: Супер, теперь работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @ArturKharchenko пожалуйста. Также буду благодарен, если проголосуете за ответ, нажав стрелочку вверх)

Comment: Рад бы, но не могу. Не позволяет низкая репутиция, необходимо 15 баллов.